# How to validate the contents of the object stream before deserializing?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

We are trying to implement secure application framework and as part of that to avoid denial of service attacks before deserialization we want to achieve how many objects are being deserialized and abort the deserialization when a threshold is surpassed.

TO meet above requirement googled some of the forums and came to know that there are some methods realted to java serialization i.e

```
resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc)
resolveObject(Object obj)
```

But i didn't get any documentation or examples regarding these two methods.Can somebody post me or give some brief info regarding these methods/custom deserialization

Answer (score 1):

Both methods you are looking for are in `java.io.ObjectInputStream` class ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)). IBM has a good article explaining look-ahead Java deserialization [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-lookahead/). Basically you can subclass `java.io.ObjectInputStream` and override the `resolveClass()` method to verify the class you are deserializing is the class you are expecting, as below:

```
public class LookAheadObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

    public LookAheadObjectInputStream(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    /**
     * Only deserialize instances of our expected Bicycle class
     */
    @Override
    protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        if (!desc.getName().equals(Bicycle.class.getName())) {
            throw new InvalidClassException(
                    "Unauthorized deserialization attempt",
                    desc.getName());
        }
        return super.resolveClass(desc);
    }
}
```

Comment: The IBM article doesn't solve anything that I can see. By the time `resolveClass()` is called it is already too late: the object has already been deserialized and could have done any kind of collateral damage in its own `readObject()` method.

Comment: @EJP My understanding is when you call `readObject` method, `resolveClass` is called before actual serialized data is read. It would throw an exception to avoid the actual deserialization from happening.